# Has Lubuntu 16.04 LTS reached End of Public Support?

Tags: discussion

Text in the last paragraph at this [web link](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released) seems to limit flavour support: "Maintenance updates are provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Base, and Ubuntu Kylin. All the remaining flavours are supported for 3 years." Has Lubuntu 16.04 LTS reached End of Public Support  & is  unsupported as suggested in comments at [Lubuntu in PowerPC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168667/lubuntu-in-powerpc) ?

Comment: I never even noticed that the flavours have shorter life cycles then the main version. 16.04 lasts until April 2024 and I would be very surprised if anyone here objected to supporting all the official flavours until then. If your question is "Does Ask Ubuntu support Lubuntu 16.04 until 2024" I would say yes. Interesting question.

Comment: @MarkKirby Did you mean April 2021?

Comment: @Mark Kirby Isn't it SOP to use the Standard Support EOL date, and when an OP says "but, I paid for Extended Support", gently refer them to Canonical?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, got confused on terminology, yes 2021 @Kulfy & K7AAY

Comment: @MarkKirby I feel the term EOL is sometimes confusing. For Canonical, release goes EOL after 5(Standard support)+3(ESM) years. But for [ubuntu.se], it is after the end of standard support. Yeah I find the terminologies little confusing and I talked about it [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51160516) which actually started from [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51152197) and was triggered by [that answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK85q.png). This was for 14.04. (*Thanking Eliah Kagan for providing the screenshot to a <10k user :D*)

Comment: @Kulfy perhaps we might consider replacing 'EOL' here with 'EOS' ? https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic Questions that you should avoid: {snip} 
Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their Support or "End of Life" (EOL) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: @K7AAY Frankly speaking, I think *"End of Public Support"* is a better term like [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions) mentions. Moreover, ESM is provided via some private archives. So yeah "End of Public Support" is better IMHO.

Comment: According to https://lubuntu.net/downloads/, 16.04 seems to be the latest Lubuntu LTS version. LTS is not even mentioned in the article https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-released/. However, other sources like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS) and [lubuntu.me](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-released/) say 18.04 _is_ an LTS release. And now what?

Comment: @Melebius, http://lubuntu.net is unofficial; their About  page http://lubuntu.net/about states so. "lubuntu.net is maintained with ♡ by Free and Open Source contributors from Asia, Linux Fans and the lubuntu Meilix community. Thank you! Get in touch here. The content of the site has been created since 2009 by Mario Behling and lubuntu contributors, who hold the Copyright and have released the content under a free CC license or GPL v3 such as the derivative logo using the LXDE logo and Trademark. This site and its content are are not related to commercial activities of Canonical."

Comment: `http://lubuntu.me` is the official site, there are more than one what we (*Lubuntu team*) refer to as 'fan' sites (like lubuntu.net) but I come across lubuntu.net most as it's in english (other sites are in other languages).  Flavors having 3 years (or less, eg. Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **NOT** a LTS release) is normal and 5 years only ever applied to 'main' repo software, 'universe' software is on a per package basis for LTS releases and 9 months for non-LTS.

Comment: With 14.04 LTS reaching EOL I noted a difference in Canonical who want to retire use of EOL term on the Ubuntu Fridge (and elsewhere for LTS releases) and thus didn't like my reference to 14.04 LTS reaching EOL & requested it be changed. Being 'community' (non-Canonical) I used precedent of prior years, but suspect this will re-occur in future and this is just more people noticing the terms & wiki's being slowly changed by Canonical staff.

Comment: If you get confused on whether or not a flavor site is real, my suggestion is just use https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours as that's in Canonical/Ubuntu's control - and will point you to the one official Lubuntu site (*of the many that exist*) or whichever flavor you're interested in

Comment: ^ clarification on my prior comment; all packages found on the flavor LTS release are supported for the time-period stated in their respective release announcement, or if you cannot find that statement - the *main* release statement, eg. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/ for 16.04.6 (skipping the ML original); so the per-package statement primarily relates to other packages in 'universe' (which I didn't state) and for other repositories it's .....

Comment: There's a related question (and answers) in the main "Ask Ubuntu" web site that I believe is relevant for this discussion:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/920392/support-time-of-other-ubuntu-lts-flavours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) Released!](http://lubuntu.me/xenial-released) (from the [confirmed](http://askubuntu.com/a/1071325/197910) official [Lubuntu web site](https://lubuntu.me)) says "Lubuntu 16.04 LTS will be supported until April 2019, with three years of support." That pretty much settles it; it has reached EoPS (End of Public Support). Fortunately, they have published [Lubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) in 32-bit and 64-bit editions.

The *unofficial* [site](http://lubuntu.net) [About](https://lubuntu.net/about) page is the place where 16.04 appears as the last LTS distro. Why unofficial? It states so.

> lubuntu.net is maintained with ♡ by Free and Open Source contributors
>   from Asia, Linux Fans and the lubuntu Meilix community. Thank you! Get
>   in touch here. The content of the site has been created since 2009 by
>   Mario Behling and lubuntu contributors, who hold the Copyright and
>   have released the content under a free CC license or GPL v3 such as
>   the derivative logo using the LXDE logo and Trademark. This site and
>   its content are are not related to commercial activities of Canonical.

Comment: I'm unsure what that means in practice. Lubuntu consists of packages in Ubuntu's repos, installable on *any* Ubuntu system. Packages in the repos (including universe) get community support until the Ubuntu release they're for is EOL. If some particular packages are considered unsupported, it would be good to know which ones! Even then, I think it wouldn't make sense to refuse to allow questions due to the presence of *specific packages*. One of my systems is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, installed with no GUI, with `lubuntu-desktop` later installed. I don't know if that's Lubuntu or not for this purpose.

Comment: Nope, that's Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, not Lubuntu. I don't generate the verbiage, I just recycle it. Policy is made well above my head.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL  it shows offiziell to me.

Comment: @nobody I _like_ that page. TY for finding it!

Comment: @Melebius, lubuntu.me is official, as per https://askubuntu.com/a/1071325/197910 and I'd linked to the release blog of that official site.

Comment: @Melebius, done.

Comment: FYI: `lubuntu.net` is also NOT the official location of information - that's `lubuntu.me` - lubuntu.net is NOT under the control of the Lubuntu team.

Comment: @Thomas Ward Absolutely correct; see my Aug 28 comment to the question above.